# Setting up payment plans

Tags: civimember, payment

I was wondering how can you set up membership payment plans (ie. installments of £2 a month for a year)?

Comment: Hi - welcome to SE! If you could provide some further details on your Civi version, CMS and what payment processor you are using I'm sure someone will be able to provide some guidance.

Comment: In addition to Lars' answer there is this which adds some extra options for this type of requirement. This is just for info, it is not a recommendation as we have not had reason to use it: https://civicrm.org/extensions/membership-extras

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Edit Membership Type and set Auto-renew to required with a duration of one month and a price of £2, does that do what you need or are you looking for something different?